# Local vs Global (image not showing)

Tags: laravel, windows, ubuntu, photo

In my laravel project the photos appear on the live site but not on the local. I think I got this error when I switched from windows to ubuntu. What is the reason?

**local:**
[image]

**live site:**
[image]

Comment: Check your browser's console for the reason.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) my console.
but the photos appear in my friend's local

Comment: About the explanation you posted in the answer (that should have been an edit): Perhaps you are composing a path incorrectly, or the current directory is not what you expect. It might have worked in Windows "by accident". You will need to check how the storage path is defined in your code.